# Shortcutting PHP's classes in a namespaced environment

Tags: php, namespaces

This is me being picky... but currently I have to use `\` in front of all my classes...

```
    //credit card expiration years and months
    $expirationYears = array();
    $expirationMonths = array();
    $datePeriod = new \DatePeriod(new \DateTime(), new \DateInterval("P1Y"), 5);
    foreach ($datePeriod as $year) {
        $expirationYears[] = $year->format('Y');
    }
    $datePeriod = new \DatePeriod(new \DateTime('January 1st'), new \DateInterval("P1M"), 11);
    foreach ($datePeriod as $month) {
        $class = new \stdClass();
        $class->value = $month->format('m');
        $class->label = $month->format('M');
        $expirationMonths[] = $class;
    }
```

Is there a way around this or is that just something that's required in a namespaced environment?

I consider it unreasonable to specify a `use` for each class... that's too tedius to maintain

Comment: That `use` keyword is the exact right way to go. It's not that much overhead. We use it big time in a project, and it's not a big deal. Using backslashes all the way through now *that's* tedious.

Comment: @DanLee: Sounds like an answer to me.

Comment: @WesleyMurch Thanks I formed it into one :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `use` keyword is the exact right way to go. It's not that much overhead.

We use it big time in a project, and it's not a big deal.
Using backslashes all the way through now *that is* tedious.

Also, it's great to keep track of all classes you use in some files which may be a couple of thousands lines long. So you can go to the top and see what classes are in use (without using in-text search).